# remove line in text file with bash if the date is older than 30 days

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
test10 2016-05-30 207
test11 2016-06-01 207
test12 2016-07-20 207
test13 2016-07-21 207
test14 2016-07-25 207
```

And I want to remove the lines from the text file if that date is older than 30 days. How can I do this? I have read some aboud `sed` but not sure if it can be done or how to go about doing it.

Comment: Can you specify the tools you have available? It's possible to implement this with `sed` and GNU `date`, but I'm hard-pressed to come up with a fully correct implementation that doesn't rely at least in part on either GNU date, GNU awk, or an entirely non-POSIX-specified tool such as `perl`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nice thing about YYYY-MM-DD is that its alpha sort is identical to its sort order as a date object -- so you can just generate a string representing the cutoff date and compare to that.

If you have GNU date:

```
cutoff=$(date -d 'now - 30 days' '+%Y-%m-%d')
awk -v cutoff="$cutoff" '$2 >= cutoff { print }' <in.txt >out.txt && mv out.txt in.txt
```

It's also possible to rely on GNU awk (`gawk`) rather than GNU date:

```
gawk -v current="$(date +"%Y %m %d %H %M %S")" \
  'BEGIN {
     cutoff_secs = mktime(current) - (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
   }

   {
     line_secs=mktime(gensub(/-/, " ", "g", $2) " 00 00 00")
     if (line_secs >= cutoff_secs) { print }
   }' <in.txt >out.txt && mv out.txt in.txt
```

Note that the latter implementation starts at the current time 30 days ago, rather than at the beginning of the day 30 days ago; replace `%H %M %S` with `00 00 00` if you don't want this behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton, I'm curious -- what's your take on feasibility of implementing this without any GNUisms at all?

Comment: It's not possible entirely in awk and even if you used `date` to get the current date and subtract 30 days you'd have to handle leap days and DST (which you'd have to define/calculate per TZ to be portable). It's possible but a PITA, not something I'd ever take on.

Comment: actually... I THINK I vaguely recall having to do stuff like this pre-GNU by doing something like using `touch -a` to create files in a temp directory with the given timestamps for their names plus access times and then `find -atime 30` (or whatever it was) to find the ones whose access time was 30 days ago. Not exactly efficient!