# How subtract days from date in bash shell on Solaris 11?

Tags: bash, date, solaris, subtraction, sunos

I've been trying subtrac some days `$days` from a date `$date` with format `yyyy-MM-dd`, but nothing has worked on Solaris 11. Some solution is a 'trick' with the timezone, but it depends on the timezone and I think that is exactly that, a trick.

I would like a cheaper solution, because the only thing I can think is to convert the date to julian representation and then subtract one day and again obtain yyyy-MM-dd representation, for example:

```
date=2000-12-31
days=1
julian=$(toJulian $date)
resultJulian=$(subtractDays $julian $days)
resultGregorian=toGregorian $resultJulian
```

So, how can I do it without all this proccess? Thanks.

Comment: What matters isn't really that it's bash, but which version(s) of `date` you have available. Some Solaris systems will have GNU tools installed, even if not in the default PATH.

Comment: unless  your system has the GNU core-utils package installed, this is probably as good as you can do. Hm.. you're just showing p-code here so you won't really be calling "functions", you'll be submitting special args to `date`. Look to convert to some `-s` (seconds since 1970) value, and subtract 24*60*60 seconds from that value. If you have GNU utils, there should be a separate `date` cmd with much expanded date-math abilities. I also think later versions of `gawk` can do date math as well, but you'll have to do `man gawk` to find out for sure.

Comment: BTW, `resultGregorian=toGregorian $resultJulian` is running whatever `$resultJulian` expands to as a command, with `resultGregorian` temporarily set to `toGregorian` in the environment. Surely that's not what you want.

Comment: @shellter, ...yup, definitely, but if the OP has `gawk`, they have GNU tools, so they might have `gdate` too.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : yep, I wasn't sure how widely the `gdate` (`g(yourCmdHere)`) convention was followed. Good luck to all.

Comment: btw, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571524/remove-line-in-text-file-with-bash-if-the-date-is-older-than-30-days/38571595#38571595 -- while not directly on-point -- provides answers that cover using either `gawk` or `gdate` (though in that answer it's just used as `date`, but when installed on a system with a non-GNU OS-provided `date` implementation, the name is generally prefixed).

Comment: ...if you don't have any of those, you'll probably end up needing to use `perl`.

Comment: Thanks to all, @CharlesDuffy you're right, it was a very fast example. I can't to know if GNU tools is installed because and is hard to me install new packages in computer's customer.

Comment: (btw, when I was testing my answer earlier I had a `days` environment variable set, which masked a bug; it's now fixed up to work in a clean environment).

Comment: btw, when you say "bash", you *really* mean bash? Because the default shell on solaris is very much not bash, or necessarily even POSIX sh -- I'm not sure about 11, but in quite modern times they were the last vendor still shipping 1970s-era `^`-is-a-pipe-character Bourne.

Comment: (Try running `echo ^ true`; if it emits `^ true` you have at least a POSIX-compliant shell; if it emits nothing, you have ancient Bourne).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. FYI: Bash is default shell in Solaris 11, but even before then (since 2005) it wasn't a problem because you would just start your script with `#!/bin/bash` if you wanted bash regardless of what user's default shell was.

Comment: @peterh, lotsa folks have a history of writing `#!/bin/sh`, and/or a habit of invoking scripts with `sh foo`. Sure, you can invoke the right tool if you know what you're doing, but one can't necessarily assume that that's a category everyone falls into -- we have *lots* of folks asking questions in the bash tag about scripts they invoke with `sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have GNU date or GNU awk, consider `perl`:

```
subtractDays() {
  local date numDays
  date=$1
  numDays=$2

  date=$date days=$numDays perl -e '
    use Env qw(date days);
    use Time::Piece;
    use Time::Seconds;

    my $start_time = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%Y-%m-%d");
    my $end_time = $start_time - (ONE_DAY * $days);
    print $end_time->ymd . "\n";'
}
```

...thereafter:

```
subtractDays 2000-12-31 1
```

...emits...

```
2000-12-30
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not GNU date and GNU awk installed and makes me think that Solaris customer doesn't have too. About Perl, yes, I have Perl, but we can ensure that perl is included in a clean/default installation of Solaris? I'm seraching for that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. And if it's not, you're stuck without any tools for date math unless you can compile a program in C that does what I just did here.

Comment: Ok, done!, I search abaout that, Perl is preinstalled at least in Solaris 11. It is enough for me. By the way, in your example, `subtractDays 2000-12-31 1` emits `2000-12-30`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution for Solaris 11:

```
#!/bin/bash
mydate="2016-08-01"
days=3
date_in_the_past=$(gdate -d "${mydate} - ${days} days")
```

You may wonder why I use `gdate` when you say it is not available?

Well, GNU Date is in fact available by default on a Solaris 11 install. It is accessed by the `gdate` command (full path is `/usr/bin/gdate`).

Some background:  GNU Date is part of "GNU Coreutils" package and this package gets installed on any Solaris 11 server unless your customer has actively selected to exclude it. I doubt that is the case.

So `gdate` is there somewhere, but you say you can't find it?  The reason is probably that you are in a local zone, not the global zone. This particular package doesn't get propagated by default into local zones when they are created. This is done in a (misguided, if you ask me) effort to save disk space. This difference between global zones and local zones is somewhat unknown to many Solaris admins.

When you explain to Solaris admins that in fact the binary already physically reside on the disk then it suddenly becomes more acceptable for them to execute the command required:

from the local zone:

```
pkg install file/gnu-coreutils
```

The above command doesn't actually go outside the server. It doesn't fetch the package from a remote package repository. The command will work even if you execute it when the server is detached from any network because the package is already there on the disk. Once you explain that to your Solaris admin he's typically okay with executing the command.

Comment: FYI, the POSIX standard explicitly specifies that the namespace of all-caps names is used by environment variables with meaning to the system or shell, and sets aside the namespace of variables with at least one lower-case character for application use; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (keeping in mind that since shell variable assignments implicitly overwrite like-named environment variables, the convention necessarily applies to them as well).

Comment: ...that said, bravo (and +1) for the OS-specific guidance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Good point. Have changed the example to use lower-case vars.